# Rearrange system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let $k \in M = \{1,\ldots,m\} \subset \mathbb N $ and $i_k \in N_k = \{1,\ldots,n_k\} \subset \mathbb N$ with parameters $\alpha_k,\gamma_k^s > 0$, $\gamma_{k,r}^c <0$.
Further let $\mathbf q = (q_{k,i_k} : k \in M, ~ i_k \in N_k)$.
I wanna solve the $\sum_{k \in M}n_k \times 1$ system
\begin{align}
p_{l,j_l}(\mathbf q) = \alpha_l - q_{l,j_l}  - \gamma_l^s \sum_{h=1 \atop h \neq j}^{n_l}{ q_{l,h_l}} - \sum_{r=1 \atop r \neq l}^m{\sum_{j_r=1}^{n_r}{\gamma_{l,r}^c q_{r,j_r}}}
\end{align}
for $q_{l,j_l}(\mathbf p)$. I tried it with matlab for $m=2$ and $n_k = 2 \forall k$, but it got really messy.
I think it must be possible to have a neat formula with summation notation, but I cannot come up with a clever way to solve it.

**Edit**: Preliminary attempt.
Sum over $i_l \in N_l$ and then over $k \in M$ which gives.
\begin{align}
&p_{l,j_l} = \alpha_l - q_{l,j_l}  - \gamma_l^s \sum_{h=1 \atop h \neq j}^{n_l}{ q_{l,h_l}} - \sum_{r=1 \atop r \neq l}^m{\sum_{j_r=1}^{n_r}{\gamma_{l,r}^c q_{r,j_r}}}\tag{1}\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad &\sum_{i_l \in N_l}p_{l,i_l} = n_l \alpha_l - \sum_{i_l \in N_l}q_{l,i_l}  - \gamma_l^s(n_l-1)\sum_{i_l \in N_l}{q_{l,i_l}} - n_l\sum_{r=1 \atop r \neq l}^m{\sum_{j_r=1}^{n_r}{\gamma_{l,r}^c q_{r,j_r}}}\tag{2}\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & \sum_{k \in M}\sum_{i_k \in N_k}p_{k,i_k} = \sum_{k \in M}n_k \alpha_k - \sum_{k \in M}\left[(1+\gamma_k^s(n_k-1))\sum_{i_k \in N_k}q_{k,i_k}\right] - \sum_{k \in M}n_k\sum_{r=1 \atop r \neq k}^m{\sum_{j_r=1}^{n_r}{\gamma_{k,r}^c q_{r,j_r}}}\tag{3}
\end{align}

I think I can then somehow combine $(1)$ and $(2)$, substitute it in $(3)$ and solve for $q_{l,j_l}(\mathbf p)$.